# What number comes next in this evenly doubled sequence?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, no-computers, formation-of-numbers, number-property

I've been playing around with sequences lately and found a pretty evenly doubled sequence of single digit numbers:

> 1, 12, 30, 64, 65, 156, 175, 368, 369, 371, 752, 753, 1524, 1525, 3060, 3073, 6168, 6219, 6221, 12444, 12453, ...

###### Hints

> The given sequence is generated using a repeating sequence. If we let $G$ represent this generating sequence, then the numbers $G_0$ and $G_9$ = $1$.

---

Can you tell me what number comes next, and why?

Comment: single digit numbers?

Comment: @DanielMathias yes, the answer is a sequence of single digit numbers, exposed by understanding the presented sequence.

Comment: I assume it's not just the last digit, but it would technically work.

Comment: @PiGuy314 you’ll have to elaborate on what you mean, but you are correct that it’s not just the last digit.

Comment: I merely meant that the final digits of G0 and G9 were both 1.

Comment: Oh, G0 and G9 are 1 so technically yes lol that hint is mean to tell you two things; the starting digit and the length.

Answer (score 1):

WORK IN PROGRESS:

It must be around ....

> 24904 = = Double 1245 (= 2490) with 4 inserted somewhere

.... give or take a small increment.

Pattern:

> In the Sequence, the Digits 1 to 9 appear in cyclic order, but at various Positions in each number.
>  The remaining Digits in each number form a Sequence that is either doubling or incrementing or both.
>  The Next number must be something like 2490 with 5 inserted somewhere and one Digit incremented like 24915 or 25905
>  Then the Next number must be something like Double with 6 inserted somewhere